# Sort an array having objects that can have 3 values

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, language-agnostic

We have an array with objects such that each object has a property that can have 3 values.

Now we need to sort this array with a linear O(n) algorithm and constant memory usage.

How can we go about it ?

Is like similar to Dutch National Flag algorithm ? Or can we do count sort ? If I am not correct then what other ways can we proceed with ? This question was actually asked to one of my friends at an interview.

Comment: yes the dutch national flag algorithm can be applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rearrangement of array elements problem. Dutch national flag algorithm should do here

```
void partition(int data[], int size, int low, int high) {
  int p = -1;
  int q = size;
  for (int i = 0; i < q;) {
    if (data[i] < low) {
      swap(data[i], data[++p]);
      ++i;
    } else if (data[i] >= high) {
      swap(data[i], data[--q]);
    } else {
      ++i;
    }
  }
}
```